# IFF в MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: sql, access, office, ms-access

```
SELECT Товары.[Код товара],
    Товары.[Наименование товара],
    Товары.[Цены за ед товара],
    (Товары.[Цены за ед товара]*Заказы.[Количество, шт]*0.9) AS [Стоимость заказа со скидкой],
    (Товары.[Цены за ед товара]*Заказы.[Количество, шт]) AS [Стоимость заказа],

IIF ([Стоимость заказа]>[Средняя цена].[Средняя цена], [Стоимость заказа]*1) AS [Скидка]
INTO [Таблица 5]
FROM [Средняя цена], Заказы
INNER JOIN Товары
ON Заказы.[Код товара] = Товары.[Код товара];
```

Выдает ошибку

> Ошибка синтаксиса(пропущен оператор) в выражениии запроса "IIF
>   ([Стоимость заказа]>[Средняя цена].[Средняя цена], [Стоимость
>   заказа]*1) AS [Скидка]".

С чем может быть связана ошибка? По моим ощущениям всё согласно документации, но что не так? Благодарю

Comment: если все согласно документации, то где третий параметр  `IIF ( expr , truepart , falsepart`)

Comment: спасибо. а когда falsepart есть, то дублирует записи и игнорирует truepart - всегда вываливает в falsepart. какие могут быть причины? DISTINCT не работает. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете ссылаться на алиас [Стоимость заказа] здесь.
Можно использовать вложенные запросы, т.е. алиас задается во внутреннем запросе и используется во внешнем.

Что касается третьего параметра в IIF, то по умолчанию используется NULL.

Comment: А как вообще дебажить ms access? Столкнулся с тем, что очень тяжело устанавливать связь между реакцией access-a и реальностью. (речь о 2007 версии)